# Network shared batch file wont change registry

Tags: powershell, batch-file, registry, jscript, hta

I have following batch file:

```
powershell -Command "& {Set-ItemProperty -Path HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\WindowsStore\WindowsUpdate -Name AutoDownload -Value 2 -Type DWord}"
```

If I run it locally it does make necessary changes to the registry, however if I upload it on a shared folder and execute this batch file via a shared folder it won't change the registry.

What am I missing here exactly? It works fine if file is located on my local computer, but if I will launch it from a shared folder (without downloading locally) no changes are made.

The batch file is called via HTA file with the following code:

```
function Win10UninstallUnnecessaryApps(){
    var shell = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
    var path = '"file:\\\\fs\\FIle Share\\SA Support\\ZverTools\\Win10UninstallUnnecessaryApps.bat"'; 
    shell.run(path,1,false); 
}
```

Comment: Please delete the comment above, I've modified your question to include that information and fixed your tags to be more specific to your task. Also, you should be aware that generally `HKLM` entries require elevation, so I would expect that the code should be run `As administrator`. I also do not understand why you are running a HTML Application, which uses JScript, to run a batch file which invokes Powershell.

Comment: P.S. I think the `file` protocol need three backslashes. Escaped, this would be `file:\\\\\\`.

Comment: Looking the path, the driver nmae is missing, and most likely also the foldername `FIle` is off.

Comment: I would suggest that HTA cannot, _for security reasons_, run code to edit the system registry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know the following method is not perfect, but it was the only solution that worked for my case. This is some sort of hack method to perform registry changes executed by the HTA application. You should create a batch file that downloads your another batch file (which has registry changing code inside), after that select that specific file and use the SendKeys method to mimic click event. As soon as I updated my HTA application with the following hack, it worked well and I got my single click registry changes after all.

Here is starting batch file (executed from HTA application button) code which runs another batch file (the one which should edit registry values):

```
@if (@CodeSection == @Batch) @then

@echo off

set SendKeys=CScript //nologo //E:JScript "%~F0"

xcopy "\\fs\FIle Share\SA Support\ZverTools\Win10UninstallUnnecessaryApps.bat" "%USERPROFILE%" /y

TIMEOUT /T 2 /NOBREAK

set targetfilepath=%USERPROFILE%\Win10UninstallUnnecessaryApps.bat   
explorer.exe /select, "%TARGETFILEPATH%"

TIMEOUT /T 4 /NOBREAK

%SendKeys% "{ENTER}"

goto :EOF

@end

var WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell");
WshShell.SendKeys(WScript.Arguments(0));
```

This was the only solution that allowed me to change registry values with a single HTA application button click.

Registry value which I wanted to change via batch file (executed from HTA app) was:

```
powershell -Command "& {Set-ItemProperty -Path HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\WindowsStore\WindowsUpdate -Name AutoDownload -Value 2 -Type DWord}"
```

Answer (score 0):

As you are running the batch file from a network share, so it means that you are not in your local computer. You also need admin privileges. So you have to use this:

```
@echo off
NET SESSION >NUL 2>&1 
IF %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 GOTO elevate
GOTO admintasks
:elevate
pushd %~dp0 
MSHTA.exe "javascript: var shell = new ActiveXObject('shell.application'); shell.ShellExecute('%~nx0', '', '', 'runas', 1);close();"
:admintasks
powershell -command invoke-command -computername  TheLocalComputerName -scriptblock "& {Set-ItemProperty -Path HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\WindowsStore\WindowsUpdate -Name AutoDownload -Value 2 -Type DWord}"
```

Replace `TheLocalComputerName` with the computer you want to execute this in.

Comment: I already have this code inside the HTA file, it calls a function that triggers batch file and batch file above-listed code in it. Permissions is not a problem in this case, problem is that if you click on a batch file with your mouse (even if it is located on network folder) it will change registry entries, however, if you call it from HTA file no changes are made.

Comment: It may sound weird but mouse click makes necessary changes, but if you will call the batch file from HTA, registry settings are not changed.